# How to accept form redirections?

Tags: python, python-3.x, forms, session, python-requests

I have a code that looks for URLs with HTTP or HTTPS protocol. So far everything works fine. However, a problem arises: when I perform the login part, it works correctly, but I want that session to be maintained in everything that follows.

MYURL = http://192.168.1.65:8080/code.html

For example, let's say it finds the link  in the user.php file. Then, when you access the code.html web page, which contains the following content:

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="http://<MYWEBSITE>/reset_password.php" method="POST">
<input name="newPassword" type="hidden" value="secret" required>
</form>
</body>
</html>

<script>
document.forms[0].submit();
</script>
```

The code.html code works correctly; I have tested it manually. However, there comes a point where, when making the request with the help of the Python code, only  is requested, when it should allow redirection or automatically submit the form data.

I have made a url.text for testing, but it is only sent to , and the POST form data is not sent.

The content of the Python code that performs the requests is as follows:

```
import requests
from urllib.parse import urlparse
import re

# Login
login_url = "http://<MYWEBSITE>/login.php"
user_url = "http://<MYWEBSITE>/user.php"
target_urls = []

# Credentials
login_data = {
    "username": "<USER>",
    "password": "<PASSWORD>"
}

# Session
session = requests.Session()
login_response = session.post(login_url, data=login_data)

user_response = session.get(user_url)

pattern = re.compile(r"(https?://\S+)")
urls = re.findall(pattern, user_response.text)

for url in urls:
    response = session.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
```

In short, what I want is that when it finds a valid URL, make the request and, using the login.php session, access  and the password is successfully changed. I hope I have clearly expressed my question. thanks!

I tried adding `allow_redirects=True`, this is because the password is not changed correctly and it just stays in the  part, when it should actually submit the form data and change the password.